# Ellipse accuracy from 2D points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an ellipse which I detected from the image using opencv, where elipse is defined as `(x_centre,y_centre),(minor_axis,major_axis),angle`. I also have list of points in form `[(x1, y1), (x2,y2), ...]` which are defining where the ellipse should be in the image.

How can I find the accuracy of the found ellipse from the ellipse defined by the points?

## Update

For better understanding this is result from my actual script:
[ellipse detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAEOk.png). The red ellipse was detected from image and green dots are just loaded from file.

Less accurate example: [ellipse detection 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiqP9.png)

I need some method to validate how accurate the ellipse is to the outer points.

Comment: This seems purely a math problem: what is the distance of a point to the ellipse? Then use the sum of square distances as the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer describes one way to find how accurately a found ellipse matches the ellipse as defined by a list of points.

The first step is to create a mask image, and draw the ellipse on it.

```
mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.ellipse(mask, ellipse, 255, 5)
```

Next, iterate though the list of points and check if they are in the white part or the black part of the mask image.

```
hit, miss = 0,0
for point in cnt:
    if mask[point[0][1], point[0][0]] == 0: miss += 1
    else: hit += 1
```

This is an ellipse that fits perfectly:
[image: good fit]

Here is an ellipse that doesn't fit so well:
[image: bad fit]

This [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) can be found with the help of the function cv2.pointsPolygonTest:

```
_,ellipse_contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, 1, 2)
ellipse_contour = ellipse_contours[0]
for point in cnt:
    total_dist += cv2.pointPolygonTest(ellipse_contour, tuple(point[0]), True)**2
rmse = math.sqrt(total_dist/len(cnt))
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated, and doesn't tell you by how much each point misses. Surely a point close to the ellipse contributes less to the error than a point far away?

Comment: I agree with @CrisLuengo. I don’t even expect that any of the points would exactly met the ellipse.

Comment: @Michalides The points don't need to be exactly on the ellipse. In this example, the ellipse is drawn on the mask image with a thickness of 5px. Any point that is within 2.5px will be counted as a 'hit'. Increasing the thickness of the ellipse in the mask image means more points will be counted as hits.

Comment: I have updated my question. My first explanation of the problem was probably not very understandable.